# Connection Refused for Shinyapp Authorization - Proxy? Firewall?

Tags: rstudio, shiny-server, shiny

When I try to authorize my account for `shinyapps`, I receive the following error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to api.shinyapps.io port 443: Connection refused
```

I know that it has something to do with my proxy or firewall settings, but I do not know how to get around this.

I am not sure how to specify a proxy for \code{rcurl} and \code{curl} connections - as I think this may be the fix?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `shinyapps` package you can read the proxy documnation by running the following commands from your R console:

`?shinyapps::rsconnectProxies`